# Regex validation for us phone

Tags: lightning, javascript, regular-expressions

when I am using lighting input and using pattern its works

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <aura:attribute type="string" name="phone" />
    <lightning:input type="phone" pattern="\D*([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)(\d{4})\D*"  value="{!v.phone}" />
</aura:application>
```

but I can not use lightning:input as its adding its won style with a box I used ui:inputphone but when trying to validate in javascript with that regular ex its not working

what I am doing wrong

// all are coming false

```
  var str = "2633579000"; // true but coming false
  var str1 = "(260) 354-9306"; // expected true coming false
  var str2 = "9912226666";
  var str3 = "0011558888";
  var str4 = "1118889999";
  var patt = new RegExp("\D*([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)(\d{4})\D*");
  console.log( str + " is " + patt.test(str));
  console.log( str1 + " is " + patt.test(str1));
  console.log( str2 + " is " + patt.test(str2));
  console.log( str3 + " is " + patt.test(str3));
  console.log( str4 + " is " + patt.test(str4));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes in your regular expression. Backslashes are special characters in JavaScript strings, like in most C/Java/JS-family languages.

```
var patt = new RegExp("\\D*([2-9]\\d{2})(\\D*)([2-9]\\d{2})(\\D*)(\\d{4})\\D*");
```

yields

> 2633579000 is true
>   (260) 354-9306 is true
>   9912226666 is true
>   0011558888 is false
>   1118889999 is false